# Django: How to take my query out of my for loop

Tags: django

I got the following code, that contains `N queries`:

```
for qty in total_qty_bought:
  product_id = qty["product"]
  quantity = int(qty["quantity__sum"])
  
  try:
    method_title = (
      self.shipment_model.get(order_id=qty["order_id"])
      .method_title.replace("Hent-selv", "")
      .strip()
    )
```

To solve the issue I tried to take the `method_title` query out of the for loop like this:

```
quantity = 0
for qty in total_qty_bought:
  quantity = int(qty["quantity__sum"])

method_title = (
  self.shipment_model.get(order_id=total_qty_bought[0]['order_id'])
  .method_title.replace("Hent-selv", "")
  .strip()
)
```

> ***Note!** There will be a full refrence further down, to understand the bigger picture*

The issue in my solution is, that I am hard choosing which `dict` to enter  , as I select `[0]` before `order_id`, and not in a for loop like before, would be selecting every individual item in the loop.

Is there a more sufficient way to do this? I do not see a solution without the for loop, but `django debugger tool` tells me it creates 2k+ queries.

## CODE FOR REFRENCE

```
class InventoryStatusView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    template_name = "lager-status.html"
    cinnamon_form = CinnamonForm(prefix="cinnamon_form")
    peber_form = PeberForm(prefix="peber_form")
    pc_model = InventoryStatus
    product_model = Product.objects.all()
    order_item_model = WCOrderItem.objects.all()
    shipment_model = WCOrderShipment.objects.all()

    def get(self, request):
        # Get all added objects that hasn't been deleted
        objects = self.pc_model.objects.filter(is_deleted=False)

        # Get all added objects that has been deleted
        deleted_objects = self.pc_model.objects.filter(is_deleted=True)

        # Sum all cinnamon that isn't deleted
        total_cinnamon = (
            self.pc_model.objects.filter(is_deleted=False)
                .aggregate(Sum("cinnamon"))
                .get("cinnamon__sum", 0.00)
        )

        # Sum all peber that isn't deleted
        total_peber = (
            self.pc_model.objects.filter(is_deleted=False)
                .aggregate(Sum("peber"))
                .get("peber__sum", 0.00)
        )

        # Get the amount of kilo attached to products
        product_data = {}
        queryset = ProductSpy.objects.select_related('product')
        for productSpy in queryset:
            product_data[productSpy.product.product_id] = productSpy.kilo

        # Get quantity bought of each product
        total_qty_bought = self.order_item_model.values(
            "order_id", "product"
        ).annotate(Sum("quantity"))

        # Get the cities from the inventory model
        cities = dict(self.pc_model.CITIES)
 
        # Set our total dict for later reference
        our_total = {}

        product = Product.objects.filter(
            product_id__in={qty['product'] for qty in total_qty_bought}
        ).first()

        # Check if we deal with kanel or peber as a product based on slug
        index = 0
        if product.slug.startswith("kanel-"):
            index = 0
        elif product.slug.startswith("peber-"):
            index = 1
        else:
            pass

        try:
            # Sum the total quantity bought
            quantity = 0
            for qty in total_qty_bought:
                quantity = int(qty["quantity__sum"])

            # Get the inventory the order is picked from based on shipment method title
            method_title = (
                self.shipment_model.get(order_id=total_qty_bought[0]['order_id']) # The error
                    .method_title.replace("Hent-selv", "")
                    .strip()
            )

            # If the order isn't picked, but sent, use this inventory
            if method_title not in cities.values():
                method_title = "Hovedlager"

            try:
                # Get the total of kanel and peber bought
                kilos = quantity * product_data[product.id]

                # If there is no inventory, set it to 0 peber and 0 kanel
                if method_title not in our_total:
                    our_total[method_title] = [0, 0]

                # Combine place and kilos
                our_total[method_title][index] += kilos
            except KeyError as ex:
                print(ex)
                pass

        except WCOrderShipment.DoesNotExist as ed:
            print(ed)
            pass

        # Quantities BOUGHT! (in orders!)
        print(our_total)

        context = {
            "cinnamon_form": self.cinnamon_form,
            "peber_form": self.peber_form,
            "objects": objects,
            "deleted_objects": deleted_objects,
            "total_cinnamon": total_cinnamon,
            "total_peber": total_peber,
            "our_total": our_total,
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only do one query by using the `__in` operator:

```
shipments = self.shipment_model.get(order_id__in=list_containing_order_ids)
```

Then you can do a normal for loop in which you verify that condition.